Testing difference between two models using WAIC and degrees of freedom of WAIC
I am conducting Bayesian penalised regression, horseshoe specifically, in R using the bayesreg package see here. One model is nested within the other, i.e. to the second model I have simply used all the predictors present in the first model and added several predictors.
I want to test whether the predictors I have added to the second model add enough explanatory power to warrant their inclusion, if not I will simply use the first model. In frequentist statistics I could answer this question with a likelihood ratio test, taking the difference in deviance between the two models and seeing whether the resulting value exceeds the critical value  (for example $\alpha < .05$) for a chi-square distribution with degrees of freedom equal to the difference in degrees of freedom of the two models.
Two of the outputs from the bayesreg::bayesreg function are waic which is described in the help as "The Widely Applicable Information Criteria (WAIC) score for the model", and waic.dof which is described as "The effective degrees-of-freedom of the model, as estimated by the WAIC".
For my two models the WAICs are as follows (Model 2 more complex model): Model 1 = 1043.902, Model 2 = 1046.783.
The effective degrees of freedom for the two models are: Model 1 = 22.9001, Model 2 = 28.35734
Clearly the more complex has not added an awful lot of explanatory power, and I will probably just use the simpler model, but I would like some formal way of justifying my decision not to use the more complex model, something similar to the concept of the likelihood ratio test.
My question is does anyone know of a formal way to test the difference between two models using WAIC and effective degrees of freedom?
Any help much appreciated.

WAIC isn't meant to estimate explanatory power, but instead estimate predictive power ($p(\tilde{y} \vert y)$) - technically, estimate the expected log pointwise posterior predictive density. Consequently, better is better regardless of the degrees of freedom estimate.  See https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.04544 (a preprint of a paywalled article) for a little more information.

Thank you @jbowman, so you are saying there is no test for determining a threshold amount of increase in predictive power? Surely there are situations where the increase is so small it does not warrant the added complexity? There are rules of thumb for model comparison using loo-cv (see https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/if-elpd-diff-se-diff-2-is-this-noteworthy/20549/17),  but are you saying there are none for WAIC.

At least none that I'm aware of, but it's not my area of expertise.   Based on what it's trying to estimate, though, it seems to me that it resembles AIC in that AIC already has model complexity built into it, so you don't need to make further adjustments when comparing two AIC values.  Of course, these comparisons shouldn't be done just by looking at numbers; only you know how plausible the various models are, etc.

Actually I don't in this case. The second model involved adding interaction terms between one binary predictor (contained in the first model) and all the remaining predictors, basically examining whether there were any differences in the effects of these predictors between levels of the predictor in question. It created a lot of additional predictors for little increase in WAIC, hence my question.
